# Merging Files In Bash

Tags: file, bash, grep, cat

I have a script file that uses import and load commands to bring in scripts from other files.  I am trying to convert these scripts to a new language but it is hard to follow the variables through all of the different imports/loads.  I am trying to write a BASH script to go through a file and import all the text from the included/imported files inline where it was called.

Final Solution Used!

```
sed -e 's/\\/\//g' test.restomatic | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^(LOAD|IMPORT)/) system("cat " $2); else print;}' > /cygdrive/c/bashScripts/testing.txt
```

Sample of Original File:

```
LOAD ..\..\..\..\GlobalSuccess\IdentityShardCreate_Success.rcq
REPLACE /rest-client/request/url/*shard* "//{$OKEnv}"
EXPECT HEADER SERVER
EXPECT HEADER DATE
EXPECT RETURN-CODE 201
RUN
IMPORT ..\..\..\..\GlobalSuccess\IdentityEnvironmentCreateNewEnvironmentFromShard_Success.rcq
REPLACE /rest-client/request/url/*shard* "//{$OKEnv}/environment"
EXPECT HEADER Server
EXPECT HEADER Date
EXPECT RETURN-CODE 204
RUN
ASSIGN ShardTypeControl 1
LOOP ShardTypeControl
ASSIGN OKShard2 {$ShardNames[{$ShardTypeControl}]}
LOAD ..\..\..\..\GlobalSuccess\IdentityEnvironmentAddShardToEnvironment_Success.rcq
REPLACE /rest-client/request/url/*shard* "//{$OKShard2}/environment/{$OKEnv}"
```

Example of desired results of output file:

```
Original File (OF) Start
(OF) Line 1
(OF) Line 2
(OF) Line 3
Line 1 of Imported File - would have been (OF) line 4
Line 2 of Imported File
(OF) Line 5
(OF) Line 6
Line 1 of Loaded File - would have been (OF) line 7
Line 2 of Loaded File
Line 3 of Loaded File
(OF) Line 8
Line 1 of Second Imported File - would have been (OF) line 9
Line 2 of Second Imported File
```

Comment: please consider editing your post to include a sample of your input file, just enough so we can understand input->output. (fewer lines is OK). Also, the output you are building looks like a nightmare for any further automated post processing. However, if it is a human readable report, then it's probably OK. Good luck.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the sample output is entirely 'pseudo code' and the real output should literally be either lines from the base file or the files it was pulling from, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this can be combined in single awk command like this:

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /^(LOAD|IMPORT)/) {gsub(/\\/, "/", $2); system("cat " $2)} else print}' test.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Nice hack, but I don't think that will necessarily interleave things properly for him.

Comment: I am new to this and I have no clue what this is doing. awk turns everything in the file into references? I appreciate the help. However I can't even try to troubleshoot anything like this when it doesn't run.

Comment: @Perry: Why wouldn't it? The `system()` function is completely synchronous (since it returns the command's exit status), and it portably forces pending output to be flushed from all buffers. What am I missing?

Comment: @user1202903: AWK is a small programming language. anubhava's AWK program will check each line to see if the first "field" (`$1`) matches the pattern `/^(LOAD|IMPORT)/`. If it does match, then the program will run the system command `cat` on the second "field" (`$2`, e.g. `..\..\..\..\GlobalSuccess\IdentityShardCreate_Success.rcq`).

Comment: Are you sure it _portably_ forces pending output to be flushed before it executes? I'm not sure about that, which is why I wondered about it.

Comment: @ruakh thanks! it sounds like that would not add the line to the export file if it does not find load or import.  Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: BTW, assuming it does portably force the buffer flush, _very_ nice hack.

Comment: also, how would i call this command so that it outputs to the command line (not sure what the technical term is for the cygwin window I have open is)

Comment: missing the part where the non-load/import lines are printed.

Comment: @Perry: Yes; see ["Advanced Notes: Controlling Output Buffering with system()" in *The GNU Awk User's Guide*](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-advanced-features_002c-buffering-1428). That said, I have to correct my earlier statement a bit; I wrote about flushing output from *all* buffers, but apparently it only *portably* flushes output from the *standard-output* buffer. (Which, in this case, is all we need.)

Comment: @jheep: I just edited my answer to add `print;` statement for else case which will print the `non load/import` lines.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, that makes it almost perfect.  I am working on getting the extracted file path to reverse the slashes (\ to /) so that it will be pulled properly

Comment: You're welcome. I added another gsub awk command to replace `\` by `/`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case "$line" in
    LOAD *|IMPORT *) cat "${line#* }" ;;
    *) echo "$line" ;;
  esac
done < original.file
```

Some commentary on the code in the question:

```
cat /path/original.file | while read $line; do 
if[grep 'IMPORT\|LOAD' $line]; then               
working on it  
else  
working on it: output to file /path/testing.txt  
done
```

- Should be `while read line` (without the `$`)
- `[` is a command and requires spaces before and after: `if [ grep '...' ... ]; then`
- to have grep read the contents of a variable, use bash's "here-string" redirection
  `grep 'IMPORT\|LINE' <<< "$line"`
- missing the terminating keyword `fi` for `if` statement
- always quote variable references, unless you specifically want the side-effects of leaving the quotes off.

Comment: That's not actually doing anything different from what he did originally. It doesn't work because it won't interleave the original source file with the imported code. All you did was replace a use of backquotes with xargs.

Comment: Your revised version isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand here, you are trying to inline the IMPORTs in some scripting language you are using (which you haven't specified) so that you'll end up with a single file that contains the entire script, so that you can then go about attempting to convert said script into another (unspecified) language.

The bash script you have written would end up concatenating all the files mentioned in test.txt into an output file in the order in which they were mentioned -- it would not result in the mix of original and imported text that you are after.

I would suggest an entirely different approach. Use sed to convert the IMPORT statements either into cpp #include statements or the equivalent from m4, and then run the resulting file through cpp or (respectfully) through m4. It is a bit of a hack, but it will produce exactly the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The original script language is mostly BASH i believe, I am new here and am converting test cases to PHP. Ultimately it will need to be readable for human consumption so we can make sure the logic is intact.  I am not familiar with the cpp #include or m4 you are referring to. Initial searches weren't clear on what they might be.

Comment: IMPORT is not a command in Bash, so I don't know how that appears in your Bash scripts. "cpp" is the C preprocessor. You will find a man page for it. "m4" is a generalized macro processor, there is also a man page for it. Either may be used to import one file into another.